# No value given for one or more required parameters - C#/Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is my first time attempting to read an Access database and write each row to the console. When I execute the application I get thrown an exception that says, "No value given for one or more required parameters" on the following statement:

OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

I'm relatively new to c# programming and after hours of research, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
private void maintenanceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Use a variable to hold the SQL statement.
        string inputString = "SELECT Full_Name, First_Name, Last_Name, Company FROM CONTACTS";

        try
        {
            //Create an OleDbCommand object and pass in the SQL statement and OleDbConnection object
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(inputString, conn);

            //Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an OleDbDataReader.
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetString(1));
                    reader.NextResult();
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error_message = ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(error_message);
        }
```

In response to the commenters, I'm posting a larger piece of code to eliminate any assumptions and give a better overall picture of what I'm trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace AzFloodSquad
{
    public partial class frm1DefaultScreen : Form
    {
        //Initialize the application
        String conn_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\\Databases\\AzFloodSquad\\AzFloodSquad.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        String error_message = "";
        String q = "";
        string varReportId = "";

    public frm1DefaultScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Load the default form
    private void frm1DefaultScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
        contactsToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
    }

    //Exit the application
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    //Start the database
    private void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);
            conn.Open();
            disconnectToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            connectToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }

    //Stop the database
    private void disconnectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Close();
            disconnectToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            connectToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }

    //Clean up database whem form close button clicked
    private void frm1DefaultScreen_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        disconnectToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
    }

    private void contactsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        varReportId = "Contacts";
        q = "SELECT * " +
                "FROM CONTACTS WHERE CONTACTS.CONTACT_TYPE = 'CUSTOMER' " +
                    "OR CONTACTS.CONTACT_TYPE = 'HOMEOWNER' OR CONTACTS.CONTACT_TYPE = 'HOME OWNER' " +
                    "OR CONTACTS.CONTACT_TYPE = 'TENANT'" +
                        "ORDER BY FULL_NAME";

        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        run_Query_Parm(q);
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    //Pull data from the database using the parameter field
    private void run_Query_Parm(String q)
    {
        error_message = "";
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            a.SelectCommand = cmd;
            a.Fill(dt);

            results.DataSource = dt;
            results.AutoResizeColumns();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error_message = ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(error_message);
        }
    }

    //Clear all data from the screen
    private void clearFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        varReportId = "";
        if (this.results.DataSource != null)
        {
            this.results.DataSource = null;
        }
        else
        {
            this.results.Rows.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void maintenanceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Use a variable to hold the SQL statement.
        string inputString = "SELECT Full_Name, First_Name, Last_Name, Company FROM CONTACTS";

        try
        {
            //Create an OleDbCommand object and pass in the SQL statement and OleDbConnection object
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(inputString, conn);

            //Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an OleDbDataReader.
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetString(1));
                    reader.NextResult();
                }

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error_message = ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(error_message);
        }
    }
```

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no it can't be for the above posted code. error could be somewhere else in your code

Comment: I don't see how. The try/catch is throwing the exception. I put a breakpoint of the statement mentioned above, then used the Debugger to step through the code and it throws the exception on that line every time.

Comment: Might just be a typo in a field or table name, that often leads to this specific error. Without your table definition we can't tell.

Comment: So much can (and will) go wrong there, and so many assumptions. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the code. I've run several tests and the error is still occurring. Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: If you have Access application, open it and run the query in the designer. This may not be necessary, but offers an easy place to compare and ensure proper spelling of column and table names. Does the query run in Access? The .Net Ole DB provider won't automatically identify and load named parameters, so you must debug any misspelling yourself.  Alternatively, just execute `SELECT * FROM CONTACTS`, then call `OleDbReader.FieldCount` and `.GetName()` method to check column names.  The general idea:  Familiarize yourself with object methods and use them to debug the details. Look at online docs.

Comment: C Perkins, I did what you asked and it did not run. Then I discovered the proper syntax I needed to use for my SELECT statement. See my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @csharpMind  *Hint:* Click the help link next to the comment textbox.  It shows how to specifically mention **and notify** the intended recipient.  Otherwise no active notification is sent and the other user may never return to the question or see followup discussions, etc.  Glad you discovered an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently, I had improper syntax on my SELECT statement. When I replaced my SELECT, (shown in the first code example I posted), with the following, it worked fine:

```
string inputString = "SELECT Contacts.[Account_Number], " +
            "Contacts.[Full_Name], Contacts.[ID], Contacts.[Street], " +
            "Contacts.[City], Contacts.[State], Contacts.[Zip] FROM Contacts";
```

Comment: If it works, great!  However, there is always more to learn and strictly speaking there was *nothing wrong with the syntax* of the original statement.  It was **not** improper syntax.  Perhaps it had a misspelling, or it included column names that were not actually in the table.  More specifically, it can sometimes be required to qualify a column with the table name, e.g. `Contacts.[Full_Name]`, but it is not always required if there is no contradiction in the source of the column.  Likewise, delimiting names with `[ ]` is always valid, but not always strictly necessary.

Comment: I guess that the real problem is that one of `First_Name, Last_Name, Company` is not actually a column in the Contacts table.  That is why Access treated one of those as a parameter... an unknown reference which needed a value.